# "Disappointment is the nurse of wisdom."

Tags: quotes, proverbs

Is this an English proverb? On quotations websites, it is often attributed to Sir Boyle Roche, but it is not listed on [WikiQuote](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Boyle_Roche) (I added it to the list of unsourced quotes on the [discussion page](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Talk%3aBoyle_Roche)). Another website says its a German proverb, but I couldn't find it (my German is very basic though).

Comment: Not one I've ever heard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd call this a ***quote***, rather than a ***proverb***.

There are only 14 instances of ["disappointment is the nurse"](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22disappointment%20is%20the%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22disappointment%20is%20the%20nurse%22&hl=en&tbo=1&tbas=0&tbm=bks&ei=7zmtT9StI8Lr8QPFgKHxCg&start=10&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=ad2f67611c89a95e&biw=1203&bih=866) in Google Books. Every one for which I can view the context continues with *"of wisdom"*, and almost all of them explicitly attribute it to Sir Boyle Roche. [This](http://solitaryroad.com/pr01.html) website claims it's a "German Proverb" - but even if that were true, the fact that Sir Boyle Roche rephrased it in English wouldn't make it a proverb from our point of view.

Note the related ["**experience** is the **mother** of wisdom"](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22disappointment%20is%20the%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22experience%20is%20the%20mother%20of%20wisdom%22&oq=%22experience%20is%20the%20mother%20of%20wisdom%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_l=serp.12...0.0.6.90854.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0...0.0.YSGDY2I9r0U&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=ad2f67611c89a95e&biw=1203&bih=866), which gets 2330 hits on Google Books. Personally, I wouldn't even call *that* a "proverb" - it's hardly in the same league as ["necessity is the mother of invention"](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22disappointment%20is%20the%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22necessity%20is%20the%20mother%20of%20invention%22&oq=%22necessity%20is%20the%20mother%20of%20invention%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_l=serp.3...6174.9535.8.10009.15.15.0.0.0.0.89.1037.15.15.0...0.0.dOP2EIW4zLw&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=ad2f67611c89a95e&biw=1203&bih=866) (80,000 hits).

Comment: Apparently, the question is whether it is 'English,' not whether it is a proverb.

Comment: Neither proverb nor quote, this's been called the 'Irish bull' I hear.

Comment: @user20908: I offer no opinion on the "wisdom" embodied in the quote itself. All I'm saying is it's definitely **not** a [short pithy saying in frequent and widespread use that expresses a basic truth or practical precept](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Proverbs), because hardly anybody will ever have heard of it - regardless of whether they might agree that it embodies a "basic truth".

Comment: @user20908: I don't think there's any doubt that the words are English.  I think the question is: "Is this an English proverb?"

Comment: @J.R.: Apparently the jury is still out on that one. Obviously **I** don't think it's *"an English proverb"*, but thus far only one other person out of the 40 who've viewed this question agrees with me. Maybe the other 39 are all waiting to see if anyone is prepared to stick his head over the parapet and say *"Sure it's a proverb - where I live, people are always saying it"*.

Comment: @user20908: According to Wikipedia, an Irish bull is a _ludicrous, incongruent or logically absurd statement_. I'm not convinced “disappointment is the nurse of wisdom” fits that description.

Comment: @BrechtMachiels: I'd be disappointed to learn that it is – but at least I'd be all the more wise to have found out.

Comment: Shows no one googled Sir Boyle Roche.